# How to move files from one intranet over to another intranet via internet without ftp

Tags: iis, intranet

I'd like to move a handful of files from one intranet over to another intranet via the internet without ftp..programmatically.  I have IIS on the receiving intranet.

Comment: There's very little detail here, so I'm going to assume you don't have control of either network and can't open ports or set up web servers that are accessible on either network. So Have you considered something like Skydrive?

Comment: I have control of the receiving intranet.  But very limited control of the sending intranet.

Answer (score 2):

There's not much detail at all here for what you're trying to do.

Is this a recurring scripted job? A one-time move? Taking kilobytes of data, megabytes, or gigabytes?

Most would probably say if it's between two business sites, set up a VPN connection and transfer it that way, as the VPN would encrypt the data and bridge the networks for you.

Otherwise, look into SFTP or SCP to transfer the data.

Or look at something like rsync or rsync over SSH to encrypt and sync up the directories.

Comment: Recurring daily.  Only a few kilobytes. I am doing some exports out of ArcGIS with python and need to move the exported data over to another network.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a WebDAV server on the receiving server, map it as a dive of the source server and use robocopy or whatever file copy tool floats you boat. Of course, without some detail about what OS you're running and what you call "an intranet", there is no way to be more specific (or even tell you if you have the option to setup WebDAV)